# Python webdriver library isn't getting connected to chromedriver -- "Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver"

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Just a simple code in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent={}".format(config.USER_AGENT))
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", 
chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And the chromedriver:

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

And:

```
$ chromedriver 
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29 on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

But when I'm running a python script, it throws an exception that it's unable to connect to chromedriver:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 98, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/home/me123/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/me123/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 102, in start
    raise WebDriverException("Can not connect to the Service %s" % self.path)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

How to fix it?

Comment: just a thought. Can you restart and try?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

I did a simple check with your code on my Windows 8 Pro box running Python 3.x with two small changes. First, I have added the argument type `executable_path` to the absolute path of the chromedriver and it works fine at my end. Second, until & unless we invoke and consume the chromedriver services, we don't really need to start chromedriver through `$ chromedriver` and can continue to refer the absolute path of the `chromedriver` in our machine through our code. Here  is your own code block will open up the Google Chrome v59.0:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent={}".format(config.USER_AGENT))
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/chromedriver", 
    chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Can you consider updating me the error stacktrace generated while you execute my exact code block? Thanks